# Найти в html элементы из localStorage и добавить им класс

Tags: jquery, localstorage, сравнение

Мне нужно найти в html-таблице id="tab" строки, дубликаты которых есть в локальном хранилище, и добавить им класс.

Например, в хтмл есть таблица:

```
<table id="tab">
  <tr><td>012</td><td>112</td></tr>
  <tr><td>0123</td><td>1123</td></tr>
  <tr><td>0124</td><td>1124</td></tr>
  <tr><td>0125</td><td>1125</td></tr>
  <tr><td>0126</td><td>1126</td></tr>
</table>
```

А в localStorage ранее из этой таблицы добавлены строки:

```
<tr><td>0123</td><td>1123</td></tr>
<tr><td>0126</td><td>1126</td></tr>
```

(в localStorage по тому же ключу есть и другие строки, но они из таблиц с других страниц)

Мне требуется найти в таблице id="tab" только те строки, которые уже были ранее добавлены в lS, и добавить им класс.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это можно реализовать на jQuery.
Спасибо!

Comment: И чем же вопрос нехорош?

Comment: Тем, что следовало попытаться это сделать и показать эти попытки.

Comment: А я понятия не имею, с какого конца за решение этой задачи браться. В интернете не нашла похожего. В jQuery я новичок. Может, это и типовая задача. Вот только я не программист. Верстальщик больше

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var storedRows = [];
$(localStorage.getItem("rows")).find('tr').each(function(){
  storedRows.push(this.outerHTML);
});
$('#tab tr').each(function(){
  if (storedRows.indexOf(this.outerHTML) != -1)
    $(this).addClass('my-class');
});
```